# speech marks around text file when referring it in the terminal

Tags: command-line, text

this is an ultra noob question. but I'm learning commands in the terminal and whenever I have to reference a text file in the terminal (which I made in the text editor), I have to put speech marks around it 'like this', see the picture for what I am talking about.

the text file is **Untitled Document 1** and it has speech marks around it. why is this? can't it have an extension at the end, and if not, why not?

THank you

[the file I'm referencing is circled yellow, why does it have to have speech marks around it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1nJc.jpg)

Comment: Extensions have no meaning in Linux. A file "foo.txt" might be a text file, or it might be a movie. Spaces, however, have significant meaning: `foo bar baz` is not the same as `foo "bar baz"`. Google will happily teach your about shell syntax.

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text include all text in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

`"..."` and `'...'` are very usefull. Basically, it makes it clear that it is one file instead of multiple. Lets say you have a file called `foo bar`. If you want to edit the file, you would use nano. So `nano foo bar`. But we have a problem: nano is now going to search for a file called `foo` and a file called `bar`. We don't want that! So we're going to need to put quotes around it to say "hey, you aren't supposed to look for two files. This is one file!" Everything between `"..."` will be seen as one file, no matter how many spaces are between the words inside.

So doing `nano foo bar test` will make nano search for the files `foo`, `bar` and `test`. But if we do this: `nano foo "bar test"`, it is going to search for the files `foo` and `bar test`. Or in your case: instead of searching for `Untitled`, `Document` and `1`, you want to search for `Untitled Document 1`, so you need to quote it.

There is a difference between `"..."` and `'...'`, but you'd first need to learn about variables and how to call them. So that isn't important. When doing what you want to do, I advice using `'...'`!